# Clojure exception when reading a text file

Tags: clojure, sequence

I'm just trying to read a standard linux '/etc/passwd' file : split into records.
This appears to work (all the lines are echoed to the terminal) but throws an exception at the end ? (See below)

What's up with this program?

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(use 'clojure.string)

(defn process_file[infile] (
        (defstruct user :username
                        :password
                        :uid
                        :gid
                        :comment
                        :home_dir
                        :shell)

        (def record_separator #":")

        (with-open [rdr (reader infile)]
                (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
                        (def fields (split line record_separator) )
                        (def user_record (apply struct user fields) )
                        (println (user_record :username) )
                )
        )
        )
)

; main
(process_file "/etc/passwd")


[ after all the lines read have been output ]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap$Def cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
        at clojure.lang.Var.fn(Var.java:392)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
        at user$process_file.invoke(readfile.clj:15)
        at user$eval14.invoke(readfile.clj:26)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6514)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6955)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6915)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:283)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)


java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)


Clojure 1.4.0
```

Comment: Use local binding in your function scope using `let`. See if the problem persists. `def` and `defrecord` create and intern global vars, so they may behave differently on each call. `def` and `defrecord` are not designed to be used within function scope so a lot of unpredictable behavior can happen.

Comment: Yep, this code has very little to do with how Clojure is meant to be used. I advise some tutorials/books instead of trial-and-error programming.

Comment: Thanks. Which book would you recommend ? I am already working through 'Programming Clojure' - not a bad book at all - but I find it lacks some clear idiomatic examples (although I should probably look at the code which comes with it) and doesn't have a reference to all the different forms available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra set of parenthesis around the entire body of your function.  Removing it looks like the following (though I don't recommend writing code this way, see below):

```
(defn process_file[infile]
  (defstruct user :username
             :password
             :uid
             :gid
             :comment
             :home_dir
             :shell)

  (def record_separator #":")

  (with-open [rdr (reader infile)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (def fields (split line record_separator))
      (def user_record (apply struct user fields))
      (println (user_record :username)))))
```

In your program, you are using `def` inside a function, which is discouraged.  A more idiomatic way of writing your code is to use a namespace, and to define the struct and the record separator outside of your function, then use `let` within your function for local variables.  Reformatting the code in that way looks like this:

```
(ns scratch
  (:require
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [clojure.string :as string]))

(defstruct user-rec
  :username
  :password
  :uid
  :gid
  :comment
  :home-dir
  :shell)

(def record-separator #":")

(defn process-file [fname]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader fname)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (let [fields (string/split line record-separator)
            user   (apply struct user-rec fields)]
        (println (format "user: %s" user))))))


(process-file "/etc/passwd")
```

The above code runs, printing out the struct's created for each line of the password file.

Answer (score 4):

The cause of your exception is the extra parenthesis before your `defstruct` call. A function is expected in leading position in a form, so the compiler tries to cast the result of `defstruct` to a function, hence the exception.